# What is a pokemon's "Level" and its purpose?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am using this [IV calculator](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4tkk75/updated_iv_calculator_automatically_calculate_ivs/) by the SilphRoad Community to compute IV values. Recently, I managed to have two Pinsirs with the same Perfect Percentage, as shown here:

[image]

As you can see, both Pinsirs have `95.6%` Perfect Value, and comparing their IV Values, they have `15-15` ATK, `14-15` DEF and `14-13` STA – not much of a difference I think? But I noticed the difference on the Pokemons' Level it is `26` to `20.5`. The tooltip says:

[image]

From that I assume that a Pokemon's level is proportion to how many times it takes to power up that Pokemon to reach its current CP. So is it just another description of a Pokemon with no application in battling them?

**What is a pokemon's "Level" and it's purpose?** I hope you can also explain the difference in my example – why is it `20.5`-`26`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This level indeed indicates the Combat Power of your Pokemon. Higher level means higher CP. Each "Power Up" of your Pokemon increases this level with 0.5, but it cannot be higher then 1.5 of your current trainer level. If you catch a Pokemon, the level is random, that is why there is a difference between the two.

For this particular example, take the Pinsir with the higher level, as it will cost you less Stardust and candy to power it up. The lower one will have the same Combat Power if the IV completely match. Keep in mind that the moveset does not have to be the same, and can be a big influence. Thanks @Aequitas for this contribution

Comment: Is the assumption, that with infinite stardust and candies only the `% Perfect` column would be relevant, correct?

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 yes, it is. Because in that case you can have the most powerful Pokemon possible.

Comment: @Mathias711 of that particular species and moveset must also be considered.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Even if stardust and candies are limited, I rather still choose pokemons with higher IV, investing on right pokemons will yield the best pokemons when reached max upgrade.

Comment: @Mathias711 sadly the IV calc column of maxed Cp doesn't show the Max for both Pinsir, in your statement `Higher level means higher CP` does it mean, that those 2 Pinsir will have different CP when maxed?

Comment: @Yawz Nope. Each Pokemon species has the same maximum CP, influenced by the IVs. So same IV means same max CP.